# .Net core 2.1 OdataRout not working

Tags: .net-core, odata, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to implement a ODataController for Customers that is able to provide me uri like to query the model 
`http://localhost:1234/odata/v1/customers?$top=4`

or use the following to get one customer based on Id

`http://localhost:1234/odata/v1/customers/1`

but no matter what I try I am unable to pass the parameter to the action/function on the controller.

My code is something like this.

```
        app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
            routeBuilder.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(100).Count();
            routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoutes", "odata/v1", modelBuilder.GetEdmModel(app.ApplicationServices));
            routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
        });
```

`GetEdmModel` is basically building the model like this:

```
        builder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers")
                        .EntityType
                        .Filter() // Allow for the $filter Command
                        .Count() // Allow for the $count Command
                        .Expand() // Allow for the $expand Command
                        .OrderBy() // Allow for the $orderby Command
                        .Page() // Allow for the $top and $skip Commands
                        .Select()// Allow for the $select Command; 
                         .ContainsMany(x => x.Transactions)
                        .Expand();
```

on the controller itself i have defined the attribute routing

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[ODataRoutePrefix("v1/[controller]")]
public class CustomersController : ODataController
{

    [EnableQuery]
    public ActionResult<IQueryable<Customer>> GetCustomers()
    {
        try
        {
            return context.Set<Customer>();
        }
        catch (Microsoft.OData.ODataException ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public ActionResult<Customer> Get([FromODataUri] string id)
    {
        try
        {
            var customer = context.Set<Customer>().Where(r => r.CustomerId == id).SingleOrDefault();
```

I see that when i have the uri = `http://localhost:1234/odata/v1/customers/1` it gets passed on to the function `Get([FromODataUri] string id)` however the value of id is always null. I have tried defining `[ODataRoute("{id}")]` but even that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

OData Works with controller name.
Change `[ODataRoutePrefix("v1/[controller]")]` to `[ODataRoutePrefix("v1/Customers")]`

Change `string id` to `string key`

Comment: I am not sure if what you are suggesting is correct. `[controller]` gets replaced with the actual controller name. Also I think the same goes with the parameter name as well.

Comment: There is a github issue that uses `[controller]` in ODataRoutePrefix that say it IS NOT working, but other than that can you cite any reference that shows `[controller]` working in ODataRoute?  The source code for odata route conventions uses `entityset/key` syntax, and I see NO support for `[controller]` in OData route templates.  Even `entityset` is for matching action method names, not for templates.
https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/8e2c3a7c48e9c32519408c87ff8ea13b0e0fb961/src/Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Shared/Routing/Conventions/EntityRoutingConvention.cs

Comment: I'm building a list of posts or GH issues that try to use `[controller]` in the OData route template: https://gist.github.com/yzorg/62b7180c954a2ffaf8dd0dc89d79dca3
Feel free to add your post, or comment if you've hit this.